# Why isn't eclipse letting me type for Scanner?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I had made a program which takes info from the user about a class (Its name, data members, methods, etc.) and prints the code with indentation.
However when I run it in Eclipse (Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600), It does not allow me to type the number of Data Members and throws a NoSuchElementException.

This is my code snippet:-

```
     static void initDataMembers(DataMembers[] var, Classes belongTo) {// for
                                                                    // constructor
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter no. of Data Members in class "
            + belongTo.name + " :-");//It doesn't even let me input


        int num = sc.nextInt();


    var = new DataMembers[num];
    if (var.length > 0) {// i.e. if there are variables, init. them with
                            // constructor
        for (int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(belongTo.name + ": Data member " + (i + 1));
            var[i] = new DataMembers(belongTo);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

My output comes thus:-

```
Enter name of the class:-
Xyz
Enter no. of Data Members in class Xyz :-
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at udc.JavaBody.initDataMembers(JavaBody.java:19)
    at udc.Classes.<init>(Classes.java:40)
    at udc.UserDefinedClass.<init>(UserDefinedClass.java:8)
    at udc.UserDefinedClass.main(UserDefinedClass.java:12)
```

After further checking, I found out that the exception is only thrown when there is nothing typed. Problem is, the Eclipse console **is not even letting me input it.** Is it a problem with the software or is it my code's fault?

Answer (score -2):

While doing `Run As` go into the run configurations.

On the Arguments tab of your Java run configuration, pass your  argument(`type the input numbers separated by spaces or newline`.)

Comment: Wait, so i can't type it through the console??? Also, my program accepts the name of the class, but not the numerical value of no. of data members.

Comment: @MSach OP is using Java's scanner inputstream, I don't see any evidence the OP is asking for launch parameters.

Comment: @LeeAllan  See "Problem is, the Eclipse console is not even letting me input it. Is it a problem with the software or is it my code's fault?". That what my question address.